# How to run emacs as a systemd service with Wayland on Ubuntu 22.04+?

Tags: emacs-daemon, ubuntu, daemon

The stock systemd user service file for emacs 29.1 looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
# ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"

# Emacs will exit with status 15 after having received SIGTERM, which
# is the default "KillSignal" value systemd uses to stop services.
SuccessExitStatus=15

# The location of the SSH auth socket varies by distribution, and some
# set it from PAM, so don't override by default.
# Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

However, after my computer starts up and I login, and try to run `emacsclient -c`, nothing happens and `journalctl -u emacs -f --user` contains an error log:

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
```

After a restart of emacs (`systemctl --user restart emacs`), there is no problem in starting emacs, and the emacsclient window opens up as expected. However, after a reboot, the same problem happens - clearly having to restart emacs immediately up login defeats the purpose of setting it up as a systemd user service.

After various googling, I ended up on https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#h5o-19 which says that we need to ensure emacs is started up after Gnome by adding these lines:

```
[Unit]
Requires=org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service
After=org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service
```

The problem is that Ubuntu 22.04+ (currently running 23.10) does not have a `org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service` unit. I've tried various things like `gdm.service`, `user@%U.service` instead of gnome shell in the above section and nothing seems to work. What's the right way here?

I've also had a look at [Systemd starts emacs daemon without XAUTHORITY environment variable after upgrading to Fedora 37](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74937/systemd-starts-emacs-daemon-without-xauthority-environment-variable-after-upgrad) that mentions the same problem on gnome/x11/fedora with a slightly different solution, but that doesnt work for Gnome/Wayland/Ubuntu combination.

Comment: This is a question about Ubuntu, not Emacs.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've reposted here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1499139/how-to-run-emacs-daemon-as-a-systemd-service-with-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04